# Object oriented programming Design?

Tags: java, oop

I'm a newbie in Java programming , I was revising questions about **OOP Design** , I found a question talking about **IS-A** and **HAS-A** relationships .

I know that **IS-A** is an **inheritance** relation , and **Has-A** is **composition** , but I couldn't figure the purpose of the question.

I don't need an answer, but I want someone to explain how to add instance variables to show Has-A relationship , I know that I can express IS-A relation by extend Phrase .

The question is:

> Add extends phrases and instance variables to show IS-a and Has-A relationships between these classes .
>
> ```
>   Class Address
>    {
>
>    }
>
>   Class Business
>    {
>
>    }
>   Class City
>    {
>
>    }
>   Class Restaurant
>    {
>
>    }
>
>   Class Theater
>    {
>
>    }
> ```
>
> [Note: By Business, we mean anything that would appear in the Yellow Pages].

Comment: Where is "the question"? And what do you think should be a possible answer? Let's see your best good-faith attempt to solve the question (after you show it to us that is).

Comment: The question is add extends phrases and instance variables to show IS-a and Has-A relationships between these clases

Comment: Edit your question, show the actual question in your question above, and again, please show your best good-faith attempt at answering it. Otherwise you're cheating yourself.

Comment: First Restaurant and Theater Has-A  Address , and IS-a Bussness   , and City IS-a Address ? is that right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this will help you a little:

```
Class Address {
   City city; // HAS-A
}

Class Business {}

Class City {
   List<Business> business; // HAS-A
}

Class Restaurant extends Business{ // IS-A
    Address address; // HAS-A
}

Class Theater extends Business { // IS-A
    Address address;  // HAS-A
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A "has-a" relationship is typically represented in Java classes using instance variables.

- Depending on the nature of the relationship (one-to-one versus one-to-many, etcetera) you might use a simple type, and array type, a standard collection type ... or something more complicated.
- Depending on the requirements, there may be a variable for the reverse relationship; i.e. "component-of".
- Depending on other aspects of the requirements (well beyond the object model) you may provide getters & setters or use a different style of API. The methods may also be responsible for keeping the reverse relationship up to date.

---

In your context, the "has-a" relationship between Business and Address is 1-to-1 and (typically) doesn't require a reverse mapping.  If the City to Business relation is a true "has-a" relationship, then it is 1-to-many.

These things depend on how your are modelling the world, and to what end you are doing it.  But for an exam question, you can make plausible simplifying assumptions (IMO) provided that you note them in the answer.

@Radek's code looks good to me as an exam question answer, modulo that he hasn't shown getters and setters.  (But as I said, those methods are beyond the scope of the model ... *per se*.)

Comment: Than you for clearing the clue , ok now i understand , its confusing because am trying to understand OO and java from many resources

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do that is to have an instance field for something that a class "has".

For example, if I was to say that a Car has-a Engine, it may look something like this.

```
Class Car{
  private Engine e;

  public Car(Engine anEngine){
     e = anEngine;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I will follow @Radec answer:

```
class Business{}
class Restaurant extends Business{ // IS-A
    Address address; // HAS-A
}

Business res = new Restaurant();
if (res instanceof Restaurant){
   // Yes, res IS-A Restarant, but the reference is only a Business
}
```

IS-A is part of polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

You would create an object of a wheel class in a car class because the car has multiple wheels.